# When is the thrust produced in an ion thruster?

Tags: ion-thruster, electric-propulsion

I have read many times that the thrust is produced when the ions leave the satellite, not while they are accelerating.

I have asked the same question twice in openAI ChatGPT and it gave me two different answers and so I am confused.

Does thrust occur on the satellite when the ions being accelerated are still inside the satellite?

These are the answers from ChatGPT:

[image: first answer]

[image: second answer]

Comment: Why would you assume a CHAT system would know anything about physics? It will tend to proritise grammar/sentence structure from the learning set over the factual details. I can see the structure of a lot of text books on both those chunks, and they are just that, mashups of texts - note for example talking about fluids in a vacuum thruster.

Comment: The first para of the first word salad is pretty close but should be explicitly referencing newtons laws. F=MA so force on the spacecraft will only by happening while the ions are being accelerated.

Comment: -1 [Shall we at least temporarily ban chatbot-generated content (e.g. ChatGTP) until it becomes clearer what it means for Stack Exchange?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2999/12102) This computer-generated gobbledygook does not qualify as prior research.

Comment: Knoll’s law of media accuracy states “everything you read in the newspapers is absolutely true, except for the rare story of which you happen to have firsthand knowledge” and something similar definitely applies to chatGPT. It is excellent at *sounding* correct and knowledgeable, but ask it about anything that you're an expert in, and watch it start making mistake after mistake. It is, admittedly an impressive piece of software and good at what it does--conversation--but it is not a polymath or even an expert at anything.

Comment: @Dragongeek are you sure that it is really "good at conversation"? I can't imagine how that would be possible for the kinds of conversations I have at least.

Comment: @uhoh chatGPT is better at smalltalk, writing emails, and basic social conversation than many people I know irl.

Comment: @Dragongeek "better at" ≠ "good at". -41 is more positive than -42, but it's still below zero.

Comment: @uhoh I disagree with your downvote. One purpose of this site, and of several other SE sites, is to clear up confusion that results from poorly written but human-written textbooks, articles, and websites. This non-human bot is yet another source of confusion. I don't see a problem with asking relevant questions about conflicting material generated by that piece of garbage.

Comment: @DavidHammen the tooltip guideline for the down vote is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" and I think that characterizes this and likely many "chatterbot says"-based questions. To me, asking a chatterbot is not research effort, and the OP has not included any evidence that they "...have read many times that the thrust is produced when the ions leave the satellite, not while they are accelerating." If they cite a source or three ("many times") that something beyond chatterbot noise is saying this, I can easily reverse the down vote.

Comment: Regarding the latter chatbot answer, particularly with regard to the cut-off ending (*so to answer your question, thrust is not produced while the ions are still inside the thruster, but rather when the are expelled from the thruster and interact with*) This is cutoff and is nonsense. Ideally, there is nothing with which the exhaust interacts once it leaves  thruster. Rocket engines work best in a vacuum where there is nothing with which the exhaust can interact.

Comment: @DavidHammen: I believe there is a relevant difference between ChatGPT and a badly-written textbook. A textbook is generally expected to be correct, precise, accurate, and instructional. There is no expectation that ChatGPT is any one of those things – it says so right on its own homepage, where the authors talk about "plausible-sounding but incorrect or nonsensical answers". ChatGPT essentially generates random strings of words with no expectation whatsoever that the result makes sense. That is not true for textbooks.

Comment: While I agree that chatbots are not reliable sources of information I do think the downvotes are unfair. The poster has put effort into posing a question and is asking for clarity, and there are good answers.

Comment: @GdD ya I'm torn; I do tend to vote favorably questions that generate good answers even if there is zero research if I feel in those cases research wasn't necessary. If the question was simply zero research "Where/when does the acceleration happen?" answerable via Newton's 3rd, I would have upvoted, especially for a new user. But SE is not always 100% fair, and I must down vote a "These chatterbot answers disagree, please resolve the issue." The OP chose not to seek out any of the zillions of possible authoritative sources or other Q&A here; the question remains chatterbot-based, so -1.

Comment: Not everyone has college level physics @uhoh, I wouldn't make the assumption people understand the implications of Newton's third.

Comment: @GdD While I learned about Newton's three laws in 7th grade, the ***focus here*** is chatterbot-based questions; ignoring Wikipedia, other Q&A on this site or anything else. If one knows how to visit chatterbot sites, one can find other resources online just as easily. Still no attempt to add any, so my downvote remains.

Answer (score 8):

First off, ChatGPT doesn't provide answers.  It strings words into plausible looking sentences based on the prompts you provide.  It knows nothing and understands less.  If you rely on a chatbot for information, you will not learn anything real.

In all reaction drives, the acceleration imparted to the ship occurs at the same time the reaction mass is accelerated.

If you sit in a boat floating on water and try to throw a big, heavy rock off the stern, you and the boat will experience acceleration with every motion of the rock.  You accelerate the rock, and the reaction accelerates you and the boat.

[This video illustrates action and reaction on a hovercraft.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeNye0nTqmM)  It works just like the written example with the boat.  The hovercraft accelerates as the ball is thrown.  It also accelerates when the ball is caught.  Everytime the ball is accelerated (sped up or slowed down or just changing direction,) the hovercraft speeds up or slows down or changes direction.  It is the same in a rocket engine.  As long as the engine is accelerating the exhaust, the exhaust is accelerating the engine.

[image]
<sub>[Image from YouTube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeNye0nTqmM)</sub>

Ion thrusters and rockets are reaction drives.  You accelerate the exhaust and the reaction accelerates the ship.  The acceleration of the ship and the exhaust takes place at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

> I have asked the same question twice in openAI chatgpt and it gave me two different answers and so I am confused.

The answer to that is obvious; it is garbage.

> I have read many times that the thrust is produced when the ions leave the satellite, not while they are accelerating.

I doubt that you have read this many times since it conflicts with basic high school physics; **thrust is absolutely produced while ions are accelerating**. Depending on the type of thruster, that location might be physically inside the thruster our outside it, wherever the electric field is accelerating ions, that's where thrust is being produce.

Basically the electric field allows the ions and the spacecraft to push on each other. Stick with good ole' Newton and the [three laws](https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/beginners-guide-to-aeronautics/newtons-laws-of-motion), especially #3:

> 1. An object at rest remains at rest, and an object in motion remains in motion at constant speed and in a straight line unless acted on by an unbalanced force.
> 2. The acceleration of an object depends on the mass of the object and the amount of force applied.
> 3. **Whenever one object exerts a force on another object, the second object exerts an equal and opposite on the first.**

Caveat that "thrust" and "accelerating" require a reference frame.

Assuming you were reading a reasonable source and not Chatterbot noise, that frame would have been defined.

Answer (score 2):

Newton’s 3rd Law is pretty clear about “equal and opposite”. There is no “and then a while later…”.

ChatGPT  does not converse. It **confabulates**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confabulation This is a psychiatric term used to describe abnormal speech as a result of brain damage. It is seen in Wernicke’s Encephalopathy (better known as “wet brain”) in alcoholics. Confabulation is superficially plausible  nonsense.

We have all met  confabulators. They sit on a barstool, going on and on with great authority but little accuracy. If some one points out   they are self-contradicting, they just keep  mouthing off.

Confabulation is not lying. A liar tries to convince you of something they know to be false. A confabulator doesn’t care if they are caught in a lie. A certain politician comes to mind.

“... ChatGPT gave me two different answers and so I am confused.” Is equivalent to “Two different chronic alcoholics with Wernicke’s gave me different answers so I am confused.”

I don’t think SE should post input generated by confabulating computer programs. It muddies the waters of evidence-based discussion.

Comment: Being able to confabulate is a big step toward being able to pass the Turing test. I'm quite impressed with what CatGPT comes up with. I'd categorize it as "close but no cigar". That said, a good number of drunkards sitting at a bar most likely would also fail the Turing test. Once again, close but no cigar.

Answer (score 1):

By way of analogy, where does the thrust from a chemical rocket with a de Laval nozzle occur? The answer is that occurs at the points where the molecules in the exhaust last contacted the nozzle. From a modeling perspective, that is the last thing a modeler who is creating a model of the entire spacecraft wants to hear. We don't want to do computational fluid dynamics to model the thrust from a thruster. We want to model the thrust as if it occurs at a specific point. Computational fluid dynamics experts will grudgingly supply a fictional point for modeling purposes that represents where on average the thrust can be modeled as being applied to the vehicle.

To get back to the question, on a microscopic scale, acceleration of the vehicle with an ion thruster happens at all of the points where the to-be-ejected particles are accelerated. On a macroscopic scale, the thrust can be modeled as occurring at one point, which sometimes is modeled as the center of the exhaust plane.